# Why indicator app not showing when started with root

Tags: 12.04, unity, indicator

I'm testing a feature in psensor that requires root privilege but the app indicator applet didn't show in the unity panel when I launched the app with gksu except when it's started as normal user. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: export DISPLAY = :0

Comment: That env var is already set to ":0"

Comment: does psesnor have a dbus api?  there's that or policykit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is only one feature of psensor which requires root privilege, the disk monitoring using the atasmart library (--use-libatasmart). You can use the hddtemp instead. Do you have a specific reason to use libatasmart?

Eventually, you can change the permission of the disk that you want to monitor to avoid the need of being root, but it will open a security hole...

psensor does not use directly dbus, but the appindicator library does...

It sounds like the issue is at dbus level: https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-appmenu/+bug/592842